# Pure sine wave or modified for a Trane HVAC?

Tags: generator, emergency-preparedness

Winter is near and I want to be able to run my Trane HVAC 1 hp motor and my Dell abd Mac desktop computers off an inverter or generator.  Should I get something that puts out a pure sine wave or can I safely use less expensive, modified sine wave equipment?

Comment: You may want to start [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13143/which-kinds-of-electrical-equipment-need-a-pure-sine-wave-inverter-to-work-corre)

Answer (score 1):

the laptop  wont care if its  modified sine wave power but  if you plan on running an ac get a generator the trane is using  a 1 hp capacitor start capacitor run induction motor, it requires  a true sinewave to run  using modified will ruin it and void the waranty. also truesine inverters are very costly. you should be fine using a 25kw generator.

Comment: The computers are desk top models.

Comment: 25kw is gross overkill.  I run my whole house on 70 amp 220v service.  That equates to 140 amps at 110v, which is much less than 25kw.

Comment: you are forgetting that the starting inrush of a 1hp induction motor is quite significant. so  while you can get by on 10kw under running conditions. it will overload the geny  during  startup of the central hearing/air unit if you have a heatpump/ac the outdoor unit requires a 30A 240v circuit. and the indoor unit will be either a 15 or 20A 120v circuit the combined running load for both will be 9kw and easily twice that during starting so 25kw is not overkill if you expect to avoid brownouts for a few seconds when the heat/air-conditioning kicks in.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC Arion Mitutoyo isn't that far off, assuming single phase service, 70a x 220v = 15400w x 125% = 19KW. And that's not including any special considerations for motor starting requirements.

Comment: @user3623501   I just want to run one appliance, and he is suggesting a power supply larger than the service to my whole house.  That does not compute.

Comment: I searched a bit on the Trane website.  I did not find anything that said a non-pure sine wave would invalidate the waranty.  I did find this article: https://www.trane.com/content/dam/Trane/Commercial/global/products-systems/education-training/engineers-newsletters/control-systems-electrical-considerations/admapn019en_0106.pdf which says "Harmonics can interfere with the operation of solid-state electronics, increase current draw, and raise motor winding temperatures." Can you show me something that says the waranty can be voided by use of a non-pire sione wave power source?

Answer (score 1):

even though this is a single phase system there will be some harmonics. all systems  are susceptible to them. they are however a more serious issue on 3 phase systems. most insidious are the 3rd order harmonics.  inverters  that are not true sine  are themselves a source of harmonics and that being said so are  generators. and a contributing factor to  the harmonics problem  on any system are non liner loads  such as computers and other equipment that has a switching power supply. now if you wish to  have a fully scale able  inverter system that is  able to be tailored to your needs. im using a system made  of [these](http://unipowerco.com/shop/5kva-inverter-inv2500/) one of [these](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA8H53HD5817) and one of [these](http://unipowerco.com/shop/battery-racks-7050-series/) additional racks can be added for  more capacity as needed just like  the inverters may be paralleled as demand grows.

Answer (score 0):

Pure sine is better; no harmonics. Modified sine (really a stepped approximation) is usually close enough and cheaper; it has much weaker harmonics than the old square-wave sources and the remaining ones don't generally cause problems.

Comment: Hmmm. What do you mean by "don't generally cause problems"?  By HVAC is an expensive unit, multiple thousands of dollars.  I would not want to have to replace or repair it.  My desktop computers as well are costly to replace.  So, what are the risks and how serious are they?

Comment: Motors should ignore the difference, power supplies should filter out thd difference without strain...  Can't vouch for specific equipment but I'd probably go for it, or if time permits ask the manufacturers just to be sure.